# Opencv : TypeError: contour is not a numpy array, neither a scalar

Tags: python, opencv, numpy

I'm trying to figure out the area of greenery in my area. I have taken image at 50 metre zoom level from Google Maps and tried separating green color from the image.

These have been taken only for testing purpose. Will perform on high resolution images, if things show good results.

**Original Image :**

Note : I need to reduce it's dimension for uploading because of 2 MB max size restriction.

[image]

**Image after drawing contours on it :**

[image]

**Following is my code :**

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
image = cv2.imread('map.png')

hsv = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

# lower and upper range of green color in HSV color format
mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, np.array([75, 50, 0]), np.array([120, 100, 100]))

mask, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(mask, cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

# print cv2.contourArea(contours)

image_with_contours = cv2.drawContours(image, contours, -1, (0,255,0), 3)

cv2.imshow('CHAIN_APPROX_NONE', image_with_contours)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

**My Problems :**

1. What is an effective way for finding the **lower and upper HSV range of a color**. I found some HSV color picker but they were not of much help. Even after taking [75, 50, 0] as lower bound and [120, 100, 100] as upper bound i can see some parts of green color missed in the second image with contour.
2. Area calculation using `print cv2.contourArea(contours)` shows the following error `TypeError: contour is not a numpy array, neither a scalar`

Following didn't help me :
[OpenCV TypeError: contour is not a numpy array, neither a scalar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17628627/opencv-typeerror-contour-is-not-a-numpy-array-neither-a-scalar)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general for remote sensing, they use multi spectral, hyper spectral images to calculate the vegetation. Operating in rgb/hsv will not be so accurate. Try if you can find one.

Anyways, for the first part, its better you make an opencv track bar to find the proper hsv values. An example can be found here for  [rgb](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_trackbar/py_trackbar.html)  . As for the second part, contours is a list of all the contours found. So use-

```
for i in range len(contours):
   print cv2.contourArea(contours[i])
```

Comment: Yes, This is only for testing purpose.